# Angular Service - Subclass Constructor Required or Can't resolve all parameters for ClassName (?)

Tags: angular, typescript

Recently, I was working on a set of services which all inherit from a base `Service` class.  The base class takes a constructor (DI) parameter of `HttpClient`.

When using autocomplete with the subclass, I can see that their constructor parameters properly account for the fact that the base class requires `HttpClient`. However, unless I explicitly put a dummy constructor in the subclass, Angular complains at run-time with the following:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyService : (?).

**Why do I need a useless constructor in the subclass?**

Note my code structure is as follows:

```
export abstract class MyBaseService {

    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {     }

    ...
}
```

```
export class MyService extends MyBaseService {

    constructor(http: HttpClient) {     
      super(http);   // don't understand why we need this...
    }

    ...
}
```

**Note:** This appears to be strictly related to the abstract class; a subclass of a regular class does not seem to exhibit this behavior.

Comment: The imports are left out for brevity, but you can assume that all compiles properly.

Answer (score 4):

We ran into this same issue, and the solution was (slightly counterintuitively) to decorate the **base class** definition with the `Injectable()` decorator. Example:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export abstract class MyBaseService {

    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {     }

    // ...
}
```

```
export class MyService extends MyBaseService {

    //  A constructor is no longer required!

    // ...
}
```

The decorator causes the TypeScript compiler to emit JavaScript code that includes some type metadata, which would otherwise be missing. The Angular JIT compiler (unlike the Angular AOT compiler) requires this metadata to figure things out.

I learned this from [this helpful GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22532#issuecomment-369722416) on the Angular repo.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have tried to remove the constructor in the MyService class? 
I already had the same problem, but it was for components.
In this case I used the following solution:

The MyBaseService leaves you as follows.

```
export abstract class MyBaseService {

    constructor(
      @Injectable(HttpClient) protected http: HttpClient
    ){}

    ...
}
```

And the MyService class leaves you as follows:

```
export class MyService extends MyBaseService {
    // do something here
}
```

Try this, if doesn't work, tell me

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - are you saying to get rid of constructor-supplied parameters and inject them directly? I can do that... but I would still like to know what's going on that I'm not understanding.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if that's it, but "HttpClient" is like a class dependency, so to prevent all child classes from declaring without even using them, it's easier to inject them directly from the father class.
Again, I'm not entirely sure that this is it.

Comment: This was the most appropriate solution I found when this problem happened to me